# Issues with UDP string parsing in C

Tags: c

I'm having issues with trying to pass in and parse data.
Specifically, I need to have ([Unsigned Char] [String of any Length])  sent through UDP. The server should be able to parse this information. Unfortunately, using sscanf I am having no luck. Please help!

Client Code:

```
char sendline[1000];
sendline[0] = (unsigned char)atoi(argv[3]); // Place Number at start of Buffer
sendline[1] = (' '); // Padding For Parsing
memcpy(&sendline[2], argv[4], sizeof(argv[4])); // Write String into Buffer after space

result  = sendto(sockfd,&sendline,(sizeof(sendline)),0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
```

Server Code:

```
unsigned char test;
char strFirst [500];
char buff[1000];
len = sizeof(cliaddr);
n = recvfrom(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &len);
buff[n] = '\0'; // Null Terminate
printf("%u %s\n", buff[0], &buff[2]); // Prints Fine
sscanf(buff, "%u %s", &test, &strFirst); // Attempted Parse of Data
printf("%u \n %s \n", test, strFirst);// Prints 0 and (null)
```

Comment: That's probably because `sscanf()` isn't the appropriate tool for the job.  Why are you sending 1000 bytes regardless of whether the data is 6 or 10 bytes?  You're misusing `sizeof(argv[4])`; you probably mean `strlen(argv[4])`.  Because you're not sending the data correctly, your receiver doesn't stand a chance, does it?  Or, maybe, what you're showing as code isn't what you're really using as code.

Comment: I haven't tested but maybe pointer problem?
so.. sscanf(buff, "%u %s", &test, strFirst) ?
Try debugging with gdb would be a good idea.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback from both of you. I'm on my phone so formatting might be off. But Jonathan, you were correct in the fact that it should be strlen() and not sizeof() but I was just using this for testing. And as the other user posted, it turns out that I shouldn't be using sscanf() as you suggested. So thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your source code at server side, I detect two errors:

1- because the first argument is binary encoded (unisgned char), the print("%u"..) is working, but not the sscanf(.."%u"..) which waits a decimal value string encoded. You couldn't use the sscanf to read this value, but simply use:

```
test = (unsigned char)(buff[0]);
```

2- In the sscanf function, the '%s' specifier waits for a (char *). It could you have to use strFirst instead of &strFirst.

```
sscanf(&(buff[2]), "%s", strFirst);
```

> If you have to use only data string-encoding, you could simplify and
>   enhance the client side by using the magic 'sprintf' function.

At client side, the source code could be:

```
char sendline[1000];
int result;

sprintf(sendline,"%u %s",atoi(argv[3]),argv[4]);
result  = sendto(sockfd,sendline,(strlen(sendline)+1),0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
```

At server side, the source code could be:

```
char buff[1000];
char *strFirst;
int len,nRead,nLen;

len = sizeof(cliaddr);
nRead = recvfrom(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &len);
buff[nRead] = '\0'; // optional due to nRead = strlen(sendline)+1
sscanf(buff, "%u %s", &nLen, strFirst);
```

Thats all !!!

Comment: Awesome! We were given hints to use sscanf and I guess I misunderstood the format specifiers in the man pages. Thank you for the help and easy to understand format!

Comment: @CSStudent You should [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem.